# How do I create a DMG file on linux Ubuntu for MacOS

Tags: macosx, binary, cross-compilation

I cross compiled a program on linux for MacOS and now I want that MacOS binary to convert to DMG file for MacOS.

Is there a way to convert a MacOS binary on Linux (Ubuntu) into DMG file for MacOS?

Answer (score 5):

There are *several* ways that this can be accomplished under Ubuntu and I describe here one technique that I have tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and also tested the resulting dmg file on a colleague's MacOS computer. Out of the several techniques that have been suggested online I believe this one is the better choice!

There are only a few *relatively* straightforward steps to follow:

1. **Install some applications**: First you will need to install `hfsprogs` which is a port of Apple's Open Source tools for HFS+ filesystems:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
   ```

   This will provide the necessary tool to work with Apple's HFS+ filesystem.
2. **Create the HFS+ file**: Next you will create a 16MB dmg file and format it to HFS+ wih the following two command lines:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/my_application.dmg bs=1M count=16 status=progress
   mkfs.hfsplus -v Install /tmp/my_application.dmg
   ```

   There are a few variables here which you should look at: you can alter the `count=16` to reflect the size dmg file that you need and you can alter the volume label, given here as `-v Install`.
3. **Mount the file, copy your program**: Now you can create a mount point, mount your dmg file there, copy your program files to the mounted dmg files and then unmount it all:

   ```
   mkdir -pv /mnt/tmp
   sudo mount -o loop /tmp/my_application.dmg /mnt/tmp
   sudo cp -av my_program /mnt/tmp
   sudo umount /mnt/tmp
   ```

   The variable to alter here is of course *the actual name* of your application in the `cp` command which I have given above simply as `my_program`.

Now your completed dmg file is sitting in `/tmp/my_application.dmg` ready for deployment and testing on MacOS!

**References:**

- [How to build a dmg Mac OS X file (on a non-Mac platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform) A coverage of some of the different techniques to create a working dmg file.

Comment: Is there any likely possibility to just use a folder to create a dmg without knowing the size?